# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Z cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String in reflective toString on model class

Tags: java, maven, reflection

I have a model class in java and I overwrote the toString to provide me with a custom toString. The toString uses reflection to find the field names and values and it works when I run it locally via my ide. However when I run it via mvn agents I always seem to get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Z cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String
```

Here is the toString:

```
@SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Class<?> thisClass = Class.forName(this.getClass().getName());
        Field[] aClassFields = thisClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : aClassFields) {
            String fName = f.getName();
            fName = fName.startsWith("_") ? fName.substring(1) : fName;
            if (null != f.get(this)) {
                if (f.get(this) instanceof String || f.get(this) instanceof List) {
                    sb.append(getVariableNameStr(fName, f.get(this).toString()));
                } else {
                    StringBuilder stringArrayStr = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String s : (String[]) f.get(this)) {
                        stringArrayStr.append(fName).append(": ").append(s).append(", ");
                    }
                    sb.append(stringArrayStr);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 2);
    }
```

The line it fails on in the code is the following:

```
for (String s : (String[]) f.get(this)) {
```

Why does this pass locally and fail using mvn? 
Can anybody tell me what is incorrect about this line?

Just to clear up - the model class has 3 types of field - String, List and String array. The errored line occurs on String array entries.

A

Comment: Libraries like apache common lang have ReflectionToStringBuilder you can use. Also note that such implementation with reflections will be pretty slow. Aslo don't repeat calls to field.get, its pretty bad idea for performance.

Comment: And about code: why you assume that field is String[] if its not String or List? Also you should be filtering out static fields or synthetic ones. Can't really guess much more without code of class you are using this on, but probably something is adding more fields to this class than you are expecting, or its completely different class, like wrapped in some proxy. As `Z]` is `boolean[]` field. Some test libraries might generate such field in some places.

Comment: There are 3 types in the class - String, List and String[]. On String[] I want to handle the value differently to when its a String or a List

Comment: also why `Class.forName(this.getClass().getName());` just do `this.getClass()` using Class.forName might actually return different class in multi class loader environment or just throw class not found exception.

Comment: And I also don't really understand why you append field name to each element of this array. And I'm pretty sure that you just don't need reflections here at all.

Comment: its a model class with a lombok builder to test a rest endpoint and an ldap endpoint. The builder allows easy creation of request bodies for rest-assured and the toString creates an output that is the same as a ldif line to query ldap. Create the object and use it in both scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume its caused by some other libraries or test suite touching your code. Or some difference in configuration between local run and maven might cause your objects to be wrapped in some other proxy classes, as proxy classes are often used by frameworks like spring.
You should filter out fields that are not part of object, by removing static and synthetic fields. As like I said in comment, `[Z` is a `boolean[]` field, so for sure you are getting some extra fields here.

Also reflections are already bad for performance, and you are repeating field.get call multiple times for no reason. And I don't understand at all why you are assuming field to be of `String[]` type without checking it.

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Class<?> thisClass = this.getClass();
    Field[] aClassFields = thisClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : aClassFields) {

        //skip static and synthetic fields:
        if (f.isSynthetic() || Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) continue;
        // get value only once: 
        Object value = f.get(this);

        String fName = f.getName();
        fName = fName.startsWith("_") ? fName.substring(1) : fName;
        if (value != null) { // and use this value here
            if (value instanceOf String[]) {
                StringBuilder stringArrayStr = new StringBuilder();
                for (String s : (String[]) value) { // and here
                    stringArrayStr.append(fName).append(": ").append(s).append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(stringArrayStr);
            } else {
                sb.append(getVariableNameStr(fName, value.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 2);
}
```

I also reordered ifs to handle `String[]` case first, and use the simple generic toString for rest of possible objects, as this seems to be your case.

Also it would be much better solution to just generate normal toString method or use some libraries like `ToStringBuilder` from apache commons. As it does not look like you need to use reflections here at all.

Comment: This worked. Maybe it was simply the get(value) repeated that caused the issue. I'm still in the dark. I also dont understand how it continuously ran successfully when I ran through idea run but failed continuously when called through maven

Comment: @amadain you can just use debugger and see what is `getDeclaredFields` returning, or just print in loop all the field names and types and see what was added.

Comment: yes It worked when I ran via right click run and even right click run all tests under in intellij idea. it always passed then. It was only when I ran mvn verify that it constantly failed. My confusion is on why there was a difference in outcome from the two methods

Comment: @amadain but I just wrote you what you can do to find out what is causing that difference. Just debug or print these fields so you can see what extra field you are getting when maven is building this

Answer (score 1):

`[Z` means `boolean[]` - not `String[]`. So the field is of type boolean[].